# Where to report Javascript bugs?

Tags: javascript

Imagine this: You want to make some things with a XML element you receive in a method. So you try this:

```
function makeNiceThings(XMLDOM){
    if(XMLDOM.getElementsByTagName("err")){
        makeReallyNiceThings(XMLDOM.getElementsByTagName("err")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    }
}
```

So, Javascript tells you you're trying to call `childNodes[0]` from a null reference. But if you try:

```
  function makeNiceThings(XMLDOM){
        if(XMLDOM.getElementsByTagName("err")[0]){
            makeReallyNiceThings(XMLDOM.getElementsByTagName("err")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        }
    }
```

It works flawlessly.

However, you update the page sometimes, and both are working again, no problems at all.

I have already faces so many situations like this, that I really want to know if there is a place I can show these bizarre errors in order to make javascript even better. Google returned me nothing but places to discover **programmer** errors. Ideas?

Comment: Bugs with JavaScript itself should be reported to the bug tracker of the *browser*.  Though, chances are this is *not* a bug with JavaScript.

Comment: Well, I don't see an issue there. In the first example you may get and *empty array* which is **not** nothing. So the condition becomes true. Whereas in the second example you do what you really meant to do — check if there's an element with index 0.

Comment: Well, this **is a programmer mistake**. And no, JavaScript will not be changed to treat arrays (or rather, NodeLists/HTMLCollections) as falsy, as that would like break thousands of other web pages.

Comment: In this case, both conditions are true. So, if(true) would have the same end. The problem is that the subsequent line had different results depending on the condition used. I can't see how this is not a javascript error!

Comment: @MrGuliarte: No, in the case where you did got an exception with your first snippet, the condition in the second did not evaluate to `true`. And that's the difference. JS did behave as expected.

Comment: Report ECMAScript bugs to ECMA, DOM bugs to W3C, and implementation bugs to the implementator.

Comment: Don't report this one though, it's not a bug!

Comment: @Bergi So you are saying it launches an error because there is an exception in the condition? I'm open to accept it, but I can't mimic this in another situation! I can, for instance, show you a fiddle using an HTML Dom at which this error does not occur! But thank you in advance!

Comment: @MrGuliarte Bergi is saying that in the first case, if `XMLDOM.getElementsByTagName("err")` is an empty array, `[]`, then the `if` statement will result in true, and then an error will occur when your code tries to use the first item in that empty array. The bug is your first `if` statement will always be true if an array is passed in, even if it is empty, but you expect the array to have at least one item in it.

Comment: The question remains unanswered. I was hoping for a URL to an ecmascript bug submission page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I don't see an issue there. In the first example you may get and *empty array* which is **not** nothing. So the condition becomes true. Whereas in the second example you do what you really meant to do — check if there's an element with index 0.
Or, if you are really convinced that this is not your fault, you should do what [Rocket Hazmat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/206403/rocket-hazmat) said:

> Bugs with JavaScript itself should be reported to the bug tracker of
>   the browser. Though, chances are this is not a bug with JavaScript.

But most probably this is a mistake in the code. If there's no `err` elements, you'll get an *empty array* and the condition will be evaluated to `true`; but there's no 0th element — that's why you get an exeption.
Hope that was clear.